# Logstash gets only one result from input

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a problem with Logstash. It only matches the first occurence. For example. Im reciving data like this:

```
2015.01.01
2017.05.02
2015.08.03
2011.10.24
2010.02.25
```

And i have filter:

```
    filter{
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "(?<started>%{YEAR}.%{MONTHNUM}.%{MONTHDAY})" }
  }
```

I want have grab all dates and save it somewhere. But in the output i have only one result:

```
{
   "message":"2015.01.01\n2017.05.02\n2015.08.03\n2011.10.24\n2010.02.25",
   "host":"127.0.0.1",
   "started":"2015.01.01",       
}
```

How to tell logstash/grok to get all dates?

Thanks!

Comment: when i try to add dates to file and set file as input it works. its only not working when im sending it via HTTP

Comment: can you show your `logstash` configuration please? this could probably because you have multiline enabled

Answer (score 0):

How is your input configuration and how are you sending the data over http?

When you set the input as a file it works because it reads the file line by line and each line only have one date.

When you send it using http it seems to be sending the whole file in one line, with the line breaks as `\n`, but everything is just only one event to logstash, that's why it only matchs the first date it finds.